# Serialize part of a model in xtext

Tags: xtext

Grammar A,B extend grammar C `grammar A with C` and `grammar B with C`. Grammar `A` is transformed into grammar `B` where some of the element in `C` is copied verbatim between the two grammars.

File `a` use grammar `A` and file `b` use grammar `B`.

The current process use the code generation of `A` to create the file `b`. Which will better when handling the element in `C` that is copied verbatim

- serialize part of `a`'s model and save the segment in `b`.
- copy part of `a`'s model to the model of 'b'.

**Update 1**
Which one of the two options are better?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You might stumble over https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471331 so maybe first solution might not work although it might be better